# Apply class when element start displaying in the window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to apply a class to a arrow bottom (changing the `translateY` and `opacity` from `0` to `1`) when user scroll and start displaying the element. Happening these animation only 1 time. The arrow is just next when the menu become `fixed`. You can see an example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtisH.png).

This is the arrow:

[image]

How I can do it?

I tried with that but this don't record the offset bottom, only scrolltop:

```
      // cache the element
var $navBar = $('.arrow-down');

// find original arrow down position
var navPos = $navBar.offset().top;

    // on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        // get scroll position from top of the page
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

        // check if scroll position is >= the arrow position
        if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
            $navBar.addClass('moving');

    }); 


      [1]: https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rDjP.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)? It's native `JavaScript`, so no jQuery is required. Support is [not perfect](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver), but Safari has adopted it and it will be part of their next mobile and desktop releases. In the meantime, you can add a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill) to gain full support.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API):

> The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe
>   changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor
>   element or with a top-level document's viewport.

Once the element enters the viewport, I'm adding an `active` class to the image container. Once `active`, the arrow's container becomes fixed near the bottom of the screen (and remains visible).

```js
// Fires when element appears in the viewport
function onEntry(entry) {
  if (entry[0].isIntersecting) {
    entry[0].target.classList.add("active");
  }
}

// Instantiate a new Intersection Observer
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry);

let element = document.querySelector(".arrow-down");
observer.observe(element);
```

```css
.arrow-down {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.3s opacity;
}

.arrow-down.active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1em;
  animation: showArrowDown 1s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes showArrowDown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(1em);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora error aliquam cumque, eligendi magni natus, molestias incidunt ducimus deserunt, vitae laboriosam sunt repudiandae earum! Nostrum rem possimus aspernatur a magnam! Saepe, quibusdam! Soluta
  nam quaerat unde sunt aspernatur explicabo voluptate voluptates illo at eaque quasi tempore, velit atque deleniti maxime. Dolorem, qui molestiae culpa quas sapiente facilis repellat tempore rem. Asperiores voluptatibus nobis ex amet praesentium. Voluptatum
  officiis id hic atque quam maxime ex expedita deleniti, voluptatibus perspiciatis dolor quisquam accusamus blanditiis, in nisi pariatur fugit nam facilis harum quo. Sapiente placeat voluptate, minima ipsum at modi beatae fugiat! Consequatur, culpa vitae
  debitis voluptas maxime totam quasi modi ab eveniet excepturi illum nulla numquam, ullam voluptatibus eos earum? Numquam, consectetur? Impedit distinctio quis cupiditate ab, obcaecati ducimus inventore labore atque at. Atque eius, a explicabo animi
  quaerat officia iusto culpa sunt nesciunt perferendis commodi fuga optio ullam expedita inventore quas.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora error aliquam cumque, eligendi magni natus, molestias incidunt ducimus deserunt, vitae laboriosam sunt repudiandae earum! Nostrum rem possimus aspernatur a magnam! Saepe, quibusdam! Soluta
  nam quaerat unde sunt aspernatur explicabo voluptate voluptates illo at eaque quasi tempore, velit atque deleniti maxime. Dolorem, qui molestiae culpa quas sapiente facilis repellat tempore rem. Asperiores voluptatibus nobis ex amet praesentium. Voluptatum
  officiis id hic atque quam maxime ex expedita deleniti, voluptatibus perspiciatis dolor quisquam accusamus blanditiis, in nisi pariatur fugit nam facilis harum quo. Sapiente placeat voluptate, minima ipsum at modi beatae fugiat! Consequatur, culpa vitae
  debitis voluptas maxime totam quasi modi ab eveniet excepturi illum nulla numquam, ullam voluptatibus eos earum? Numquam, consectetur? Impedit distinctio quis cupiditate ab, obcaecati ducimus inventore labore atque at. Atque eius, a explicabo animi
  quaerat officia iusto culpa sunt nesciunt perferendis commodi fuga optio ullam expedita inventore quas.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora error aliquam cumque, eligendi magni natus, molestias incidunt ducimus deserunt, vitae laboriosam sunt repudiandae earum! Nostrum rem possimus aspernatur a magnam! Saepe, quibusdam! Soluta
  nam quaerat unde sunt aspernatur explicabo voluptate voluptates illo at eaque quasi tempore, velit atque deleniti maxime. Dolorem, qui molestiae culpa quas sapiente facilis repellat tempore rem. Asperiores voluptatibus nobis ex amet praesentium. Voluptatum
  officiis id hic atque quam maxime ex expedita deleniti, voluptatibus perspiciatis dolor quisquam accusamus blanditiis, in nisi pariatur fugit nam facilis harum quo. Sapiente placeat voluptate, minima ipsum at modi beatae fugiat! Consequatur, culpa vitae
  debitis voluptas maxime totam quasi modi ab eveniet excepturi illum nulla numquam, ullam voluptatibus eos earum? Numquam, consectetur? Impedit distinctio quis cupiditate ab, obcaecati ducimus inventore labore atque at. Atque eius, a explicabo animi
  quaerat officia iusto culpa sunt nesciunt perferendis commodi fuga optio ullam expedita inventore quas.
</p>

<div class="arrow-down">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtisH.png" alt="down arrow" />
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora error aliquam cumque, eligendi magni natus, molestias incidunt ducimus deserunt, vitae laboriosam sunt repudiandae earum! Nostrum rem possimus aspernatur a magnam! Saepe, quibusdam! Soluta
  nam quaerat unde sunt aspernatur explicabo voluptate voluptates illo at eaque quasi tempore, velit atque deleniti maxime. Dolorem, qui molestiae culpa quas sapiente facilis repellat tempore rem. Asperiores voluptatibus nobis ex amet praesentium. Voluptatum
  officiis id hic atque quam maxime ex expedita deleniti, voluptatibus perspiciatis dolor quisquam accusamus blanditiis, in nisi pariatur fugit nam facilis harum quo. Sapiente placeat voluptate, minima ipsum at modi beatae fugiat! Consequatur, culpa vitae
  debitis voluptas maxime totam quasi modi ab eveniet excepturi illum nulla numquam, ullam voluptatibus eos earum? Numquam, consectetur? Impedit distinctio quis cupiditate ab, obcaecati ducimus inventore labore atque at. Atque eius, a explicabo animi
  quaerat officia iusto culpa sunt nesciunt perferendis commodi fuga optio ullam expedita inventore quas.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora error aliquam cumque, eligendi magni natus, molestias incidunt ducimus deserunt, vitae laboriosam sunt repudiandae earum! Nostrum rem possimus aspernatur a magnam! Saepe, quibusdam! Soluta
  nam quaerat unde sunt aspernatur explicabo voluptate voluptates illo at eaque quasi tempore, velit atque deleniti maxime. Dolorem, qui molestiae culpa quas sapiente facilis repellat tempore rem. Asperiores voluptatibus nobis ex amet praesentium. Voluptatum
  officiis id hic atque quam maxime ex expedita deleniti, voluptatibus perspiciatis dolor quisquam accusamus blanditiis, in nisi pariatur fugit nam facilis harum quo. Sapiente placeat voluptate, minima ipsum at modi beatae fugiat! Consequatur, culpa vitae
  debitis voluptas maxime totam quasi modi ab eveniet excepturi illum nulla numquam, ullam voluptatibus eos earum? Numquam, consectetur? Impedit distinctio quis cupiditate ab, obcaecati ducimus inventore labore atque at. Atque eius, a explicabo animi
  quaerat officia iusto culpa sunt nesciunt perferendis commodi fuga optio ullam expedita inventore quas.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora error aliquam cumque, eligendi magni natus, molestias incidunt ducimus deserunt, vitae laboriosam sunt repudiandae earum! Nostrum rem possimus aspernatur a magnam! Saepe, quibusdam! Soluta
  nam quaerat unde sunt aspernatur explicabo voluptate voluptates illo at eaque quasi tempore, velit atque deleniti maxime. Dolorem, qui molestiae culpa quas sapiente facilis repellat tempore rem. Asperiores voluptatibus nobis ex amet praesentium. Voluptatum
  officiis id hic atque quam maxime ex expedita deleniti, voluptatibus perspiciatis dolor quisquam accusamus blanditiis, in nisi pariatur fugit nam facilis harum quo. Sapiente placeat voluptate, minima ipsum at modi beatae fugiat! Consequatur, culpa vitae
  debitis voluptas maxime totam quasi modi ab eveniet excepturi illum nulla numquam, ullam voluptatibus eos earum? Numquam, consectetur? Impedit distinctio quis cupiditate ab, obcaecati ducimus inventore labore atque at. Atque eius, a explicabo animi
  quaerat officia iusto culpa sunt nesciunt perferendis commodi fuga optio ullam expedita inventore quas.
</p>
```

Comment: It's work's like a charm!!! But how I can, imagine, have multiple div's and delay each one 0.5 sec, appearing first one, 0.5 sec wait next second one, 0.5 sec wait next second one... without making the script code for each element and apply in the custom class a animation delay of 0.5 sec?

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga It sounds like a new SO question is forming :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206507/delay-translate-elements-with-intersection-observer-api  @Andy Hoffman ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use lazysizes.
https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

The intersection Observer isnt that great, IMO.

With lazysizes you can have it lazyload all your images, as well as specify a data-expand attribute to fine tune when the image is lazyloaded in relation to the viewport.
Example:

`<img data-src="img/arrow-down.png" class="arrow lazyload" data-expand="-20" alt="Baja para ver" title="Baja para ver">`

It will change class to lazyloaded when is deemed appropriate to load in based on viewport and the data-expand flag. 
Now it's as simple as simply adding your css in to .arrow.lazyloaded