# Delay translate elements with Intersection Observer API

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to show the elements when user scrolls to the content. It works well, but I want to **delay the div's to be showed**, if there are 4 `div's`, I want the first to be showed, next 0.5 sec the next is shown... not all in the same time. In the example the effect only applies on the first `class` too, if there are more than 1 `class` like there are, it didn't apply to the next `img classes`, only the first. You can see the example in the bottom of this [page](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html).

HTML

```
<section id="staff" style="padding-top: 100px;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto mb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row icons-info">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <img class="floating show-bottom" src="img/Muñeco 1-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
          <img class="floating" src="img/Muñeco 2-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
          <img class="floating" src="img/Muñeco 3-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <img class="floating" src="img/Muñeco 1-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</section>
```

JS

```
// Instantiate a new Intersection Observer
let observer7 = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry7);
let staff = document.querySelector('.floating');

let element7 = document.querySelector("#staff p");
observer7.observe(element7);

function onEntry7(entry7) {
  if (entry7[0].isIntersecting) {
    staff.classList.add("show-bottom");
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.floating {opacity: 0; transition: 1s opacity;}
.floating.show-bottom {opacity: 1;  
  animation: movefromtop 1s alternate infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;}
@keyframes movefromtop {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-5em);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0em);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all inner div elements, then using `forEach` call your `observer.observe()` method for all elements. Then in the observer, use the `target` property to query the inner image and add the `show-bottom` class to it.

To add a delay between each animation you have to create an animation chain by returning a `Promise` and using `setTimeout()`. Also make sure to not chain the same element more than once in the animation if the intersection triggers many times for the same element. For this, use an array of `animatedElements` to keep track of the elements being animated.

If you only want to animate the elements once, after begin intersected, you can call `unobserve` on your observer to unregister from further intersection events.

Note: I edited your HTML/CSS to make the grid work in the snippet to demonstrate the sequential animation effect when multiple elements are on the same row. I also added a `with-img` class to the inner divs so we can query them and pass them to the observe method.

```js
const onEntry7 = animateSequence('.floating', 'show-bottom');
const observer7 = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry7);
const allElements7 = document.querySelectorAll('#staff div.with-img');
allElements7.forEach(e => observer7.observe(e));

function animateSequence(targetSelector, classToAdd, delay = 500) {
  const animatedElements = [];
  let chain = Promise.resolve();

  function show(e) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        e.classList.add(classToAdd);
        res();
      }, delay);
    });
  }
  return function(entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        const elem = entry.target.querySelector(targetSelector);
        if (!animatedElements.includes(elem)) {
          animatedElements.push(elem);
          console.clear();
          console.log('chaining', ...animatedElements.map(e => e.getAttribute('data--name')));
          chain = chain.then(() => show(elem));
          observer7.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.floating {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s opacity;
  width: 157px;
  height: 220px;
}
.floating.show-bottom {
  opacity: 1;  
  animation: movefromtop 1s alternate infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;
}
@keyframes movefromtop {
  from { transform: translateY(-5em); }
  to { transform: translateY(0em); }
}
section#staff {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
Scroll Down
<section id="staff" style="padding-top: 100px;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto mb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row icons-info">
        <div class="with-img col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <img class="floating" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 1-08.png" data--name="1">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="with-img col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
          <img class="floating" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 2-08.png" data--name="2">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="with-img col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
          <img class="floating" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 3-08.png" data--name="3">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="with-img col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <img class="floating" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 1-08.png" data--name="4">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</section>
```

Comment: Can check my page?https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html  I applied it but still showing the first element only... I don't know what im doing bad

Comment: @Pedro Corchero Munga, I updated the answer to include the delay and fix a bug, then I inserted my code in your page and it now works well. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah it's work's well now, but is there any possibility to avoid the effect reset when I mouseout the image? It's because I have a transform when :hover and when mouseout the intersection observer resets, can I force it to happens only 1 time? Check my page, U will see what happen when u mouseout any of the class floating's images.

Comment: @Pedro Corchero Murga, Glad that it works! I saw that you left the console.clear and console.log calls in your code, you can remove them as they are no longer necessary. Regarding the effect reset, I suggest to apply your hover style only once the images are inserted, so when show-bottom is inserted I think

Comment: I just clear it, thanks. How I can apply the hover style only when the images are inserted? Thanks.

Comment: @Pedro Corchero Murga, hmm good question, could you post this as a separate question with the related CSS ? I quickly looked into your code and it's not so easy to solve it I think and not related to the delay problem this question was about.

Comment: @Pedro Corchero Murga, I will be glad to try to answer the other question as well though

Comment: Thanks @jo_va, i will question it. Here we go! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208057/avoid-intersection-observer-resets-when-mouseout-element