# Avoid animation reset on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few images with a class added dynamically to them by an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to trigger a translate animation when the user scrolls to them. I simply added the class to the images in this snippet.

On each image, I also have a `:hover` animation that gives them a 'buzz' effect.

However, when the user mouseout the parent div, the first animation replays. It seems I have a conflict between both animations.

How can I avoid this ?

```css
.floating {
  width: 150px;
  height: 220px;
}

.show-bottom {
  animation: movefromtop 1s alternate;
}

@keyframes movefromtop {
  from { transform: translateY(-5em); }
  to { transform: translateY(0em); }
}

.icons-info > *:hover .floating { 
  animation: buzz 0.15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes buzz {
  from { transform: translateX(3px) rotate(2deg); }
  to { transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-2deg); }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<section id="staff">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto mb-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row icons-info">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <img class="floating show-bottom" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 1-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
          <img class="floating show-bottom" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 2-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 ">
          <img class="floating show-bottom" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 3-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <img class="floating show-bottom" src="https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/img/Muñeco 1-08.png">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nibh justo, tincidunt sed felis vitae, egestas scelerisque eros. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</section>
```

Comment: I changed your code to a runnable snippet, but could you add the hover class and the part responsible for the transform reset ?

Comment: Added, sorry, I forget it.

Comment: Your problem is not related to the intersection observer, this is a CSS problem, I commented out the JS code and your problem persists

Comment: So, is a CSS Bug? Can't fix it?

Comment: It is a CSS bug, I am looking for a fix, would you let me edit your question ? Maybe somebody will come up with a fix faster

Comment: Yes, sure. Can we talk by chat? I just saw that when transform rotate or scale it didn't happens, the bug only happen's when animation keyframes!! I tried with scale rotate:hover instead animation keyframes and the bug didn't happens. PD: I'm spanish too haha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190210/discussion-between-pedro-corchero-murga-and-jo-va).